# Getting Trust: Self Created Certificate Authority

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, ssl-certificate

I was messing around with OpenSSL, learning to create my own Certificate Authorities, User and Server Certificates and such, then test them with a HTTPS Node app.

In the end, I had to provide my browser my Intermediate Certificate Authority Certificate in order to get past ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error, even though in my app I was passing my Certificate Authority Chain Bundle to it correctly.

So my question is, how do I make/gain trust to my Intermediate Certificate Authority automatically, without me or my Users having to manually add the Certificate?

I am aware that there are certain Certificate Authorities out there that have implicit trust and are automatically included, but that isn't the only way is it?

Comment: One of the main PKI fundamentals is explicit trust to root certificate. This means that you will have to manually install your root certificate to client devices in order to trust it. If clients would trust arbitrary certificates sent be server, the whole purpose of PKI is compromised.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.